# Как сделать endpoint api для редактирования/создания связанных один ко многим полей модели

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Есть следующие модели (упрощенно):

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class StreamField(models.Model):  
    article_id = models.ForeignKey(Article, related_name='streamfields', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=True)
    content = models.TextField()
```

Я хочу получать по api все StreamField, связанные с одним Article. Так-же хочу иметь возможность, редактирую Article, создавать/редактировать для нее новые StreamField.

Мои сериализаторы выгдятят так:

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    streamfields = serializers.RelatedField(many=True, read_only=False,
                                                      queryset=StreamField.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('title', 'datetime', 'streamfields')


class StreamFieldSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = StreamField
        fields = ('article_id', 'content')
```

Вьюхи так:

```
class ApiArticleViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer


class ApiStreamFieldViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = StreamField.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StreamFieldSerializer
```

При создании новой Article, я могу выбирать только из существующих StreamField, а хочется сразу создавать. Я представляю, что можно сделать через APIView, но это очень низкоуровнево. Хотелось бы знать, есть-ли способ лучше.